# Flutter List View Builder Using API

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

I am able to fetch data from API and I can show it in the List View, but **i want to show the first card as the latest updated data.**
I tried to use the Reverse property of List View Builder, it some how solve my problem but gave rise to another problem. Now i need to scroll upward in order to see latest updated data.
Help me through it
I just want to show the latest updated data at the top and then scroll down to see another data.

Please Help Me.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;

class PromotersDetails extends StatefulWidget {
final String url,title;
PromotersDetails({Key key, @required this.url, @required this.title}) : super(key: key);
 @override
 _PromotersDetailsState createState() => _PromotersDetailsState(url,title);
  }

class _PromotersDetailsState extends State<PromotersDetails> {
fetchSelfies() async {
var url1;
url1 = await http.get(Uri.parse(
    url));
var res = json.decode(url1.body);
print(res);
return json.decode(url1.body)['selfies'];
 }
    String url,title;
_PromotersDetailsState(this.url, this.title);
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.6;
 return Scaffold(
  backgroundColor: Colors.white,
  appBar: AppBar(
    centerTitle: false,
    title: Text(
      title,
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.white),
    ),
    elevation: 0.0,
    backgroundColor: Colors.green,
  ),
  body: FutureBuilder(
      future: fetchSelfies(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.hasError) {
          return Center(
            child: Text(snapshot.error.toString()),
          );
        }
        if (snapshot.hasData) {
          return ListView.builder(                        **// List View Builder**
            reverse: false,
            cacheExtent: 10000.00,
            itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(8),
            itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
              return Row(
                children: [
                  Container(
                    height: 120,
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Container(
                      height: 120,
                      width: 120,
                      child: Card(
                        child: Image.network(snapshot.data[index]['image']),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                 
                  Expanded(
                    child: Container(
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: [
                          SizedBox(
                            height: 10,
                          ),
                        
                          Row(
                            children: [
                              Text(
                                "Time: ",
                                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                              ),
                              Text(
                                snapshot.data[index]['time'],
                                style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff868597)),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
           
                          Container(
                            height: 50,
                            child: Text(
                              snapshot.data[index]['location'],
                              style: TextStyle(color: Color(0xff868597)),
                            ),
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              );
            },
          );
        }
        return Center(
          child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
        );
      })

  );
 }
}
```

Comment: from the API if you are getting the data as the latest to older then why are you doing the reverse property. Simply populate the data in the list view.

If you are getting data as older to latest [Considering the factor that all data is in single go, else with pagination its not possible, you need to get the api updated] you can keep the data in list object, call reverse method on that object and then populate the result in list view builder

Comment: Thankx I got the API Updated And its workimg

Answer (score 0):

If you just need to sort the API response backwards, you can use the `reverse` property of ListView.

```dart
ListView.builder(
  reverse: true,
  ...
),
```

If the way you're populating the ListView is by appending new data, then it's better to store the data on a List then do sort/reversed. Though the sorting should be best done at the backend instead of passing the burden to the client app.